# JavaScript cant find function in onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, html, image

My html:

```html
<!doctype hmtl>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var playerId = 1;
        function event(action) {
            let req = new XMLHttpRequest('/act?id='+String(playerId)+'&action='+action);
            alert(action);
        }
    </script>
    <img src="up.png" width='100' height='100' onclick='event("up");'>
    <img src="down.png" width='100' height='100' onclick='event("down");'>
    <img src="left.png" width='100' height='100' onclick='event("left");'>
    <img src="right.png" width='100' height='100' onclick='event("right");'>
    <img src="fire.png" width='100' height='100' onclick='event("fire");'>
</body>
</html>
```

I know for sure the image is clickable. But why does the error message say `event is not a function`? I need help.

Comment: Just rename the function; `event` is not allowed.

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way, you are trying to access the global object `window.event`, so just rename your function.

Your own code, renaming the function `event` to `test`:

```html
<!doctype hmtl>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var playerId = 1;
        function test(action) {
            let req = new XMLHttpRequest('/act?id='+String(playerId)+'&action='+action);
            alert(action);
        }
    </script>
    <img src="up.png" width='100' height='100' onclick='test("up");'>
    <img src="down.png" width='100' height='100' onclick='test("down");'>
    <img src="left.png" width='100' height='100' onclick='test("left");'>
    <img src="right.png" width='100' height='100' onclick='test("right");'>
    <img src="fire.png" width='100' height='100' onclick='test("fire");'>
</body>
</html>
```